How to reference system_integration in IBM watson assistant action builder "Assistant Says" section
I'm seeing a weird behavior that just started this month.  I have where I'm sending a JWT with the user's information in it as part of the identityTokenExpired event for watson assistant.  That works fine.  Previously I used to be able to reference the user id out of the system_integration in the "Assistant Says" section by putting in something like Your user ID is: ${system_integrations.channel.private.user.id}.  It would display out the email address that was stored in the sub of the JWT.
Now when I put the same information in there I get Error When Validating Operation: can only contain word, underscore, hyphen or dot characters, and must not start with a prefix of "sys" or "system" or "user_defined_"..  How do I reference the system_integration variables in the "Assistant Says" section.  In the Set variable values section I can pull the value out and store it into a session variable using an expression ${user} = ${system_integrations.channel.private.user.id}.
So, the values are there, just how do I access them directly in the "Assistant Says" section?  Is there a way to add an expression in the area?
Images below show the error that I'm getting and a workaround for now.


